# how do you release a thread when it finishes

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion

I have an application that recursively walks a very large (6 TB) folder.  To speed things up, I create a new thread for each recursion.  At one point my thread count was in excess of 12,000.  As the task gets closer to completion, my thread count gets drops, but on Task Manager the thread count keeps climbing.  I think that indicates that the threads are not being garbage collected when they finish.

At one point, my internal thread count showed 5575 threads while the Windows resource monitor showed the task using 33,023 threads.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string folderName = Properties.Settings.Default.rootFolder;
    ParameterizedThreadStart needleThreader = new ParameterizedThreadStart(needle);
    Thread eye = new Thread(needleThreader);
    threadcount = 1;
    eye.Start(folderName);
}

static void needle(object objFolderName)
{
    string folderName = (string)objFolderName;
    FolderData folderData = getFolderData(folderName);
    addToDB(folderData);

    //since the above statement gets executed (my database table
    //gets populated), I think the thread should get garbage collected
    //here, but the windows thread count keeps climbing.
}

// recursive routine to walk directory structure and create annotated treeview
private static FolderData getFolderData(string folderName)
{
    //Console.WriteLine(folderName);
    long folderSize = 0;
    string[] directories = new string[] { };
    string[] files = new string[] { };
    try
    {
        directories = Directory.GetDirectories(folderName);
    }
    catch { };
    try
    {
        files = Directory.GetFiles(folderName);
    }
    catch { }
    for (int f = 0; f < files.Length; f++)
    {
        try
        {
            folderSize += new FileInfo(files[f]).Length;
        }
        catch { } //cannot access file so skip;
    }
    FolderData folderData = new FolderData(folderName, directories.Length, files.Length, folderSize);
    List<String> directoryList = directories.ToList<String>();
    directoryList.Sort();

    for (int d = 0; d < directoryList.Count; d++)
    {
        Console.Write("  " + threadcount + "  ");

        //threadcount is my internal counter.  it increments here 
        //where i start a new thread and decrements when the thread ends
        //see below
        threadcount++;
        ParameterizedThreadStart needleThreader = new ParameterizedThreadStart(needle);
        Thread eye = new Thread(needleThreader);
        eye.Start(directoryList[d]);
    }

    //thread is finished, so decrement
    threadcount--;
    return folderData;
}
```

Comment: Why is the class FolderData static?

Comment: You are creating the thread inside the scope of a for loop.  The reference to that thread is disappearing before the thread has completed it's work.  The garbage collector will get to it eventually.  If you want to monitor the threads more closely, you need to keep a reference to each thread you create and call .Join for each one.  Threads aren't something that you should be worrying about cleaning up, but more worrying about creating.  In your case you are creating far too many threads to get a positive parallel return.  I would recommend you use the TPL for this and let it deal with things.

Comment: Your `threadcount` will drop when the thread execution reaches the code to decrement it, but that doesn't mean the thread is actually closed. You need to check the value of `eye.ThreadState` to verify if the thread has actually completed and is awaiting garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks jdweng; FolderData class is not static. though the routine  getFolderData is static.  I think i would get an exception if it wasn't static since its parent class is not actually instantiated.

Comment: Thank you Abion47,  I will try that to monitor the threadcount.

Comment: Thanks matt-dot-net. What is TPL?   In general I would agree with you about the threads, but in this case when I limit the number of threads, it severely limits the performance (based on the rate at which records get added to the database).  I think it is because of the amount of I/O wait associated with walking the directory.

Comment: *threadcount--* is executed only once, isn't it? Whereas *threadcount++* is executed as many times as the number of iterations in the for loop above it.

Comment: I also recommend using Task Parallel Library (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) so that you don't need to deal manually with Threads. This operation you try to perform seems to require no sequentiality, so it should be an easy use case.

Comment: 12,000 threads, all fighting over *one* shared resource.  Yikes.  Especially a bad idea on spindle drives, they don't like to be jerked around by multiple threads.  Use only one thread to read files from a drive.  Any data processing on the file data, the stuff that is actually compute-bound and for which you have multiple cores, can be spun off on multiple worker threads.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to matt-dot-net's suggestion I spent a few hours research TPL (Task Parallel Library), and it was well worth it.

Here is my new code.  It works blazingly fast, does not peg the CPU (uses 41% which is a lot but still plays nice in the sandbox), uses only about 160MB of memory (instead of nearly all of the 4GB available) and uses a maximum of about 70 threads.

You'd almost think I new what I was doing.  But the .net TPL handles all the hard stuff, like determining the correct number of threads and making sure they clean up after themselves.

> class Program
>       {

```
    static object padlock = new object();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        OracleConnection ora = new OracleConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ora);
        ora.Open();

        new OracleCommand("DELETE FROM SCRPT_APP.S_DRIVE_FOLDERS", ora).ExecuteNonQuery();
        ora.Close();

        string folderName = Properties.Settings.Default.rootFolder;
        Task processRoot = new Task((value) =>
        {
            getFolderData(value);
        }, folderName);
        //wait is like join;  it waits for this asynchronous task to finish.
        processRoot.Start();
        processRoot.Wait();


    }

    // recursive routine to walk directory structure and create annotated treeview

    private static void getFolderData(object objFolderName)
    {

        string folderName = (string)objFolderName;
        Console.WriteLine(folderName);
        long folderSize = 0;
        string[] directories = new string[] { };
        string[] files = new string[] { };
        try
        {
            directories = Directory.GetDirectories(folderName);
        }
        catch { };
        try
        {
            files = Directory.GetFiles(folderName);
        }
        catch { }
        for (int f = 0; f < files.Length; f++)
        {
            try
            {
                folderSize += new FileInfo(files[f]).Length;
            }
            catch { } //cannot access file so skip;
        }
        FolderData folderData = new FolderData(folderName, directories.Length, files.Length, folderSize);
        List<String> directoryList = directories.ToList<String>();
        directoryList.Sort();

        //create a task for each subdirectory
        List<Task> dirTasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int d = 0; d < directoryList.Count; d++)
        {


            dirTasks.Add(new Task((value) =>
           {
               getFolderData(value);
           }, directoryList[d]));

        }

        //start all tasks
        foreach (Task task in dirTasks)
        {
            task.Start();
        }
        //wait fo them to finish
        Task.WaitAll(dirTasks.ToArray());
        addToDB(folderData);
    }

    private static void addToDB(FolderData folderData)
    {
        lock (padlock)
        {
            OracleConnection ora = new OracleConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ora);
            ora.Open();

            OracleCommand addFolderData = new OracleCommand(
                "INSERT INTO FOLDERS " +
                "(PATH, FOLDERS, FILES, SPACE_USED) " +
                "VALUES " +
                "(:PATH, :FOLDERS, :FILES, :SPACE_USED) ",
            ora);
            addFolderData.BindByName = true;
            addFolderData.Parameters.Add(":PATH", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            addFolderData.Parameters.Add(":FOLDERS", OracleDbType.Int32);
            addFolderData.Parameters.Add(":FILES", OracleDbType.Int32);
            addFolderData.Parameters.Add(":SPACE_USED", OracleDbType.Int64);
            addFolderData.Prepare();

            addFolderData.Parameters[":PATH"].Value = folderData.FolderName;
            addFolderData.Parameters[":FOLDERS"].Value = folderData.FolderCount;
            addFolderData.Parameters[":FILES"].Value = folderData.FileCount;
            addFolderData.Parameters[":SPACE_USED"].Value = folderData.Size;
            addFolderData.ExecuteNonQuery();

            ora.Close();
        }

    }

}
```

}